# Deactivate current object in array and activate next one by using button click?

Tags: unity

How to deactivate current object in array and activate next one by using button click?

```
public GameObject[] gameObjects;
private int numOfgameObjects;

void Start()
{

  //current object
  gameObjects[0].SetActive(true);

  int numOfgameObjects = gameObjects.Length;

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfgameObjects ; i++)
  {
      gameObjects[i].SetActive(false);
  }

}

public void NextPrefab_ButtonClick()
{
  // Some Code to deactivate current object and activate next one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty trivial: just track the index of the current selection in a variable, and increment that variable when you want to select the next item. You may want to work your way through some beginner C# tutorials if this use of variables is unfamiliar.

```
public GameObject[] gameObjects;

// Track which object we've currently selected.    
int _selectedObjectIndex = -1;

public void SelectObject(int selectedIndex)
{
    // Disable the previous selected object, if any.
    if(_selectedObjectIndex >= 0)
        gameObjects[_selectedObjectIndex].SetActive(false);

    // Update our selected index and activate the corresponding object.
    _selectedObjectIndex = selectedIndex;
    gameObjects[selectedIndex].SetActive(true);
}

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        gameObjects[i].SetActive(false);
    }

    SelectObject(0);
}

public void NextPrefab_ButtonClick()
{
    // Compute the next index in the list.
    // The modulo operator % "wraps" our index around to zero when we pass the last object.
    int nextObjectIndex = (_selectedObjectIndex + 1) % gameObjects.Length;
    SelectObject(nextObjectIndex);
}
```